# Include BItcoinJS library in electron project

Tags: node.js, electron

I was wondering how to include the [Bitcoin JS Library](https://bitcoinjs.org/) in my electron project. I tried running `npm install` inside the project directory and creating a `var` to use it but it does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a `package.json` in your project directory? If so, does it have Bitcoin JS inside the `dependencies:`?  If not, run `npm init` and fill out the fields that it asks for or just hit `enter` several time to leave them blank.  After that you should have a `package.json` file.  Now run `npm install bitcoinjs-lib --save`. You should now have BitcoinJS in your `node_modules` folder and it should be included as a dependency in your `package.json`.

Comment: That did it ! Thanks !